# Terraform conditional if in for_each

Tags: terraform

I have the following code using `for_each` to iterate over mapped values:

```
resource "null_resource" "win_vm" {
  for_each = var.vms_to_image
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
    type     = "winrm"
    https    = true
    insecure = true
    user     = var.vm_username
    password = random_password.vm_password.result
    host     = element(azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.win_vm.*.public_ip_address, each.value)
    use_ntlm = true
    }

    inline = [
      "ipconfig"
    ]
  }
}
```

This works fine and creates the WinRM connection for every machine I need to connect to.

How can I incorporate this resource as being conditional? Something like `if var.create_vm_images == "Yes" then for_each = var.vms_to_image`

I used to use count to do this, but wanted to get it working with `for_each` as it keeps the value of the variable map.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
for_each = var.create_vm_images ? var.vms_to_image : {}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as each.value is empty. 
Error - A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it
unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in
its "for_each" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your
configuration to work around this error.

Comment: Worked like a charm for what I was trying to do, thanks. I just had to use a for in the for_each: 
`for_each = {
        for v in (condition ? conditional_collection : {}) : v.some_field => {
            name   = v.name
            desc  = v.description
        }
    }
`